# Weblogic server hangs when "Creating data source connection pool named"

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have just installed Weblogic version 10.3.6.0 and created a data source which connects to MSSQL on my localhost. I have tested my connection and verified that a successful connection can be made from the admin website.

On restarting my admin server, my admin server hangs when it is starting up.

[image]

A look at my log files seem to indicate that there is problem creating a data source as that is the last event before the server hangs

[image]

[Here](http://kickasspastes.com/4356/) are my server log files in full

I have tried Googling but it seems nobody has the same problem as me, anyone has any clue to what is happening and possible solutions??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Will be late for you, but will help others in the future.

I was facing the same problem than you today. After 2 hours of test I, finally, figured out what to do to been able to start the WebLogic console.

Go to `C:\Oracle\was\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\jdbc` and **temporarily** move the JDBC file is causing the problem to a temp folder.

In the next restart of the WL server, you will get some warns about that file not existing, but Console will start and you will be able to do other things (like reconfiguring de JDBC).

`<05-may-2016 11H59' CEST> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141230> <Could not locate the descriptor file for System Resource: jdbc/yourdeletedjdbc`

Now, go to the WebLogic console, go to JDBC datasources and you will see a "blank" datasource (the one you moved). Ok, restore the moved file again, refresh the datasource screen and you will see the original datasource. Now you can remove it with the console and build a new one.